# "Machen" or "tun" in "Was würdest du an meiner Stelle [verb]"?

Tags: word-choice

> Was würdest du an meiner Stelle machen?
>   Was würdest du an meiner Stelle tun?

And is "an meiner Stelle" more common or "in meiner Lage"?

Comment: For the 2nd part regarding "an meiner Stelle" versus "in meiner Lage": are they total synonyms?

Comment: I guess "an meiner Stelle" is more common than "in meiner Lage" because it carries stronger emotional binding of the situation (for translations that grossly exaggerate this difference: "if you were me" as opposed to "if you happened to be in a more or less comparable situation")

Answer (score 0):

"In meiner Lage" is "in my situation / position / condition" and therefore not 100% interchangeable with "an meiner Stelle" (/"In my spot" aka "if you were me").

also "an meiner Stelle tun" sounds way more natural, though both your ideas are grammatically correct.

Source:
Native speaker